# Preventing page reload on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

am trying to prevent this form from causing the whole page to refresh. When I've searched elsewhere on here, the answer is usually to use return false; However, this is already in the code but it's still reloading the page

```
<input type="submit" name="PC13871$btnRefresh" value="Search" onclick="(function(btn){var bDisableMe=true;if(typeof(Page_ClientValidate)=='function'){bDisableMe=Page_ClientValidate('PC13871');}__doPostBack('PC13871$btnRefresh','');btn.disabled=bDisableMe;})(this);return false;" id="PC13871_btnRefresh" class="BBFormSubmitButton DirectoryFormSubmitButton"></input>
```

Anyone got any ideas? This code is generated by a CMS so I can attack it with javascript/jQuery but can't just edit the html unfortunately.

Edit: live example here - https://community.crisis.org.uk/no-one-turned-away/election-actions/no-one-turned-away-ppc-support#constituency

Comment: do yourself a favor put your javascript in a `<script>` tag so it's legible.

Comment: Looks like some kind of server-side validation is happening there, you might not be able to avoid reloading... By the way, which CMS is this ?

Comment: @Alex it's Blackbaud Net Community

Answer (score 0):

Elsewhere here is right: **if you return false your button won't submit**.

Therefore:

1. either your button is not returning false, or
2. something else is submitting the form.

To check **1**, put a return false at the very beginning of the onclick statement. Then you can go moving the return until you have tested the whole onclick.

You can also add an `[alert][1]` to ensure the code has reached your return line. Do not use console.log for this purpose, because it doesn't stop the flow.

After this, to find out **2**, you can open the console on Google Chrome and review the most likely assigned elements. Focus on the form and check at the right (on the console) the section Event Listeners. Do the same with your button.

Note: do not use `event.preventDefault()` until you are sure what (and why) is submitting the form. Doing so is not only bad practice, but you'll run into troubles in the future for sure.

Comment: Hi @Ale I think your solution would work but unfortunately I can't edit the html of the submit button. It's generated by a part on our CMS. I'll try it in Developer anyway and if it works will script it in somehow.

Comment: Hey @PaulMcCarthy. I see. Yes, it's been a long time since I debugged inline js scripts, but I think you can still use the Developer Console (Chrome) to debug it. Let me know if you have a problem.

Answer (score -2):

```js
$("#PC13871_btnRefresh").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit" name="PC13871$btnRefresh" value="Search" onclick="(function(btn){var bDisableMe=true;if(typeof(Page_ClientValidate)=='function'){bDisableMe=Page_ClientValidate('PC13871');}__doPostBack('PC13871$btnRefresh','');btn.disabled=bDisableMe;})(this);return false;" id="PC13871_btnRefresh" class="BBFormSubmitButton DirectoryFormSubmitButton"></input>
```

Use the `e.preventDefault()`. It will cancel the default action for an input of type `submit`

Comment: Please do not provide jQuery solutions when it is not needed

Comment: @bviale, please check if the posted question has `jquery` as one of its tags and let me know, please. Furthermore, how do you know the OP doesn't _need_ a `jquery` solution? And finally, what is needing a `jquery` solution? Thank you for the downvote

Comment: Hi @chiapa It didn't work, but yes, a jQuery solution would be absolutely fine. I put your script in and it did run because the alert came up when clicking the submit button. I've commented that line out but it's still on the page. Have a look if you have time [https://community.crisis.org.uk/no-one-turned-away/election-actions/no-one-turned-away-ppc-support#constituency]

Comment: Thank you @user3755818, I did visit that link but I'm not sure what should I do to test your issue

Comment: Hi@chiapa, many thanks for your continued help. If you select a consituency from the dropdown and press Search you will see that the whole page reloads and you are back at the top of the page. That is the problem.

Comment: @user3755818, what is the expected behaviour for that button?

Comment: @chiapa Think you're looking at the wrong section. Further down the page at this point: https://community.crisis.org.uk/no-one-turned-away/election-actions/no-one-turned-away-ppc-support#constituency under the Search your constituency heading is a widget that retrieves info from a directory.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy, I realized that and so I edited my comment. What's the expected behaviour for that button then?